# Bug detect, go channels with select

Tags: go

There is supposed to be a bug in this bit of code. My mate told me that it contains a memory leak and it occurs when the time out case happens in the select statement before the go function has finished and he also told me that adding a buffer of size one to ch would solve the problem. But i have a hard time understanding why it would solve the problem and would appreciate if someone could explain if for me? I've tried to search for the answer myself but with no success.

Thanks.

```
func Read(url string, timeout time.Duration) (res *Response) {
    ch := make(chan *Response)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 300)
        ch <- Get(url)
    }()
    select {
    case res = <-ch:
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        res = &Response{"Gateway timeout\n", 504}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that a channel without a buffer, called synchronous, will block both the sender and the receiver until they can complete their exchange.

Much like if you had to hand over something to your mate and you both knew the meeting place, but not the time. The first one to get there will wait for the other, whether it's the sender or the receiver. Now, given that computers are stupid :-) if one of them forgets about the appointment, the other will verily wait forever.

The specific bug here is that when the select chooses the `time.After` (that is, the timeout occurs) nobody will be there to receive from `<-ch` anymore. Not ever. So the poor `go func()` will sit there forever, waiting for someone to take her `*Response`, but nobody will ever show up.

This does not actually waste any CPU power, but it wastes memory: that needed to keep track of the channel, of the goroutine, of her stack—however small—and her local variables. The memory will never be reclaimed until the entire process terminates or is killed.

In a server, serving a lot of clients, this will build up quickly until the application eats all the memory of the server and—if you're lucky—gets killed by the OS safety measures, without taking down the entire machine.

Using a buffered channel is one way to solve the issue, because then, whenever the poor `go func()` has her `*Response` ready, she will be able to store it into the channel's buffer, even if nobody is there to get it, and terminate peacefully. As soon as that happens, Go's garbage collector will notice that no live goroutine is holding any pointers to that channel anymore, so it will collect the channel and the `*Response` it points to and recycle all those bytes.

Comment: @JakobSvenningsson I see you're new here. If this answers your question, you should click on the check mark ✔ right below the votes.

Comment: Using a buffered channel is *one* way to solve the issue, but it is probably not the only way. The case here arises because the secondary goroutine is created on the fly and in some cases is never released - essentially, that one goroutine becomes **deadlocked**. This happens every time the `Read` function is called and a timeout occurs. I am interested in what alternative solutions might be possible.

Comment: @Rick-777 I would look for a way to set a timeout on a lower level. For example, if the underlying source of this data is an HTTP or TCP connection, you can set timeouts that are passed through to the OS, or at least are implemented in the stdlib. Barring that, a select with time.After is a good solution, but it needs a buffered channel. I don't think it's worthwhile (nor easy) to implement a different solution, without incurring in data races.